# SQL Server 2008 installed but missing sqlbrowser.exe and management studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wanted to know how to detect which edition of SQL Server 2008 is installed on my PC. The answer to that question involves using sqlbrowser.exe but it seems I don't have that file in its default location. I also don't seem to have the SQL Server Management Studio.

I'm using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010... does an edition (perhaps "express") of SQL Server come with either of those? which edition would that be? Should I uninstall it and reinstall a full version or can I get sqlbrowser.exe and the management studio separately and add them on?

I know this is going to take some time, so I'd prefer to canvass people's views beforehand.

Thanks in advance for your help on this supposedly simple yet typically frustrating task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SQLBrowser and Management Studio are both optional tools in all editions - seems likely that it's the Express edition.

In the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```

usually has a bunch of data about which editions and options are installed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following SQL:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version'
```

On my dev machine this prints out "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: )".

Visual Studio install an Express edition if you don't unckeck it while installing ...

Comment: you beat me by 30 seconds, I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: Yeah it's most likely the MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS default instance from VS, it's also possible that there are other versions and instances on the machine too - it can be installed SxS.